# how to send parameter for select query using android volly?

Tags: android-volley

I am using volley library in my app  I want to pass  table name which i taking from some resource using get method for select query, so how i pass this table name using volley library.
I searched for it many sites, but not understand the concept.

Answer (score 3):

```
override the getParams()
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username","***");
                params.put("password","***");
                return params;
                }
```